# Cloudfront throws 504 while connecting to ELB/Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

So I have a NextJS application hosted on Elastic Beanstalk (with it exposed on port 3000 in the docker file). Now, I have my domain registered with Godaddy. I initially had the DNS setup in Godaddy to point to Elastic Beanstalk. But then I wanted to use cloudfront for CDN/Caching.

So, I started configuring Cloudfront (using [this article](https://medium.com/@dale.bingham_30375/creating-a-static-website-using-godaddy-github-aws-s3-codedeploy-and-aws-cloudfront-1990a8f4ddd8)). I created the custom SSL certificate and got it verified through DNS as well. I set the origin in cloudfront to points to ELB.

Now, once the cloudfront distribution was deployed, I tried using the cloudfront URL `xxxxx.cloudfront.net` but I got a `"504 ERROR - The request could not be satisfied"` error.

If I go to the ELB URL I am able to access my application. So, I am not sure what's the issue here. If the cloudfront is pointed to ELB and ELB works then why would cloudfront URL won't work.

Any advice/recommendations?

Comment: How did you setup your CF distro to communicate with EB? Maybe it tries to use https but EB supports only http, or opposite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you receive a 504 error you are getting a timeout whilst connecting to the origin.

You should check the following:

- Does the security group for the ELB allow inbound traffic from anyone (on port 80/443)? If it does not CloudFront is blocked.
- Have you misconfigured your "Origin Protocol Policy", by selecting "Match Viewer" it will expect that HTTPS requests that hit CloudFront attempt to connect to the origin via HTTPS.
- Does your application have a start time that exceeds the value of the `Origin Response Timeout`? By default this is 30 seconds.
- Ensure the origin is the correct domain name.

There are additional steps to debug a 504 in CloudFront within the [HTTP 504 Status Code (Gateway Timeout)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-504-gateway-timeout.html) page on AWS.

Comment: The "Origin Protocol Policy" was set to "Match Viewer". I have changed it to HTTP. Now it is working fine. Thanks for the help :).

Comment: @Blueboye be sure you understand the implications of making that change.  Traffic between the CloudFront Edge location serving the request -- and your origin server -- is not encrypted when the origin protocol policy is HTTP.  Only traffic between the browser and CloudFront is using HTTPS.

Comment: Yeah I do understand that the traffic between CF and Origin is not encyrpted. It is not an issue since it's just a static site I am hosting without any input fields on the site. However,  I am wondering if we should be concerned since the origin is in AWS as well. So, the CF-origin communication happens with the AWS ecosystem. Do, we still need to consider encryption if the communication is happening within AWS?